# How to write to file with overriding previous content

Tags: macos, applescript

There is a method to write data in the file:

```
to output:someThing toFile:someFile
    try
        tell application "System Events" to set myname to get name of (path to me)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to myname
        set pathToFolder to text item 1 of ((path to me) as text)
        set outputFileWithPath to (((pathToFolder) as text) & someFile)
        set fileRef to (open for access outputFileWithPath with write permission)
        write (someThing) to fileRef starting at 0
        close access fileRef
    on error errmess
        log errmess
        try -- make sure file is closed on any error
            close access fileRef
        end try
    end try
end output:toFile:
set outputFile to "test1"
(my output:"first second third" toFile:outputFile)

(my output:"forth" toFile:outputFile)
```

The issue in this example is: in the end, I will have a file with:

```
forth second third
```

The goal is to have only last record. In this example:

```
forth
```

Comment: Have a look at: [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH58-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `write (someThing) to fileRef starting at [...]` construction is meant to insert new data into a file: it overwrites data at that point in the file without changing anything else. If you want to delete the contents of the file after some certain point, use `set eof fileRef to [some integer]`. 'eof' here stands for 'end of file'. Your code would be:

```
    set fileRef to (open for access outputFileWithPath with write permission)
    set eof fileRef to 0
    write (someThing) to fileRef
    close access fileRef
```